Alignment inside a equivalent statements proof
How can I set this kind of alignment keeping 1->2 in the left hand side and having the text with a justified alignment. I assume that I have to do 1->2 manually.


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Something like this?

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsthm}   % for 'proof' environment
\usepackage{enumitem} % sophisticated controls for list-like environments
\usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text
\usepackage{newtx}    % optional (Times Roman text and math font clone)

\begin{document}

\begin{proof} \mbox{}
\begin{itemize}[itemindent = 0pt,leftmargin = 2\parindent]
\item[$1\Rightarrow 2$] \lipsum[1][1-4]
\item[$2\Rightarrow 3$] \lipsum[2][1-3]
\item[$3\Rightarrow 1$] \lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}

\end{document}


And, likely, \qedhere at the end of the last item. Of course, according to Murphy's law, the document will show “Proof” at the end of a page and the rest in the next one…

You can do it, but is it really appealing? Not to me. Anyway, I offer you a comparison: below you see how I'd do it.
I hope you don't plan to have lists inside such proofs. Don't forget \qedhere at the end of alignedproof.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\newlength{\alignedproofindent}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{alignedproof}{O{\proofname}m}
 {%
  \proof[#1]\mbox{}\par\nopagebreak
  \settowidth{\alignedproofindent}{#2\quad}%
  \everypar{\hangindent=\alignedproofindent\hangafter=0 }%
 }
 {\endproof}
\NewDocumentCommand{\alignedproofstep}{m}{%
  \par\noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[\alignedproofindent][l]{#1}%
  }\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\gives}{${{}\Rightarrow{}}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{proposition}

\begin{alignedproof}{1\gives2}
\alignedproofstep{1\gives2}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[2][5-8]

\alignedproofstep{2\gives3}
\lipsum[3][1-2]

\alignedproofstep{3\gives1}
\lipsum*[4][1-2]\qedhere
\end{alignedproof}

\begin{proof}
(1\gives2)
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[2][5-8]

(2\gives3)
\lipsum[3][1-2]

(3\gives1)
\lipsum*[4][1-2]
\end{proof}

\end{document}


